# How to use the model without the GAT module?

Tags: resnet

There is such a model (ResNet18 + GAT):

```
class AntispoofModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, device="cpu", **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        resnet = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.10.0', 'resnet18', pretrained=True)
        self.resnet = nn.Sequential(*[i for i in list(resnet.children())[:-2]]).to(device)
        for ch in self.resnet.children():
            for param in ch.parameters():
                param.requires_grad = False
        self.gat = GAT(**kwargs).to(device)
        self.device = device
        self.adj = torch.tensor(grid_to_graph(7, 7, return_as=np.ndarray)).to(device)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.resnet(x.to(self.device))
        x = x.view(-1, 49, 512)
        #adj = torch.stack([self.adj for i in range(x.shape[0])]).to(self.device)
        x = self.gat(x, self.adj)
        return torch.sigmoid(x)
```

I'm trying to do the same thing, but without GAT, for example (Sorry, I can't insert more code):

[ResNet18 without GAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76t7N.png)

But then I get an error `Using a target size (torch.Size([64, 1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([64, 49, 512])) is deprecated. Please ensure they have the same size.`

**upd:**
Now I rewrite code like:

```
class AntispoofModel(nn.Module):    
    
    def __init__(self, device="cpu", **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        model_resnet = ResNet(BasicBlock, [2, 2, 2, 2])
        self.conv1 = model_resnet.conv1
        self.bn1 = model_resnet.bn1
        self.relu = model_resnet.relu
        self.maxpool = model_resnet.maxpool
        self.layer1 = model_resnet.layer1
        self.layer2 = model_resnet.layer2
        self.layer3 = model_resnet.layer3
        self.layer4 = model_resnet.layer4
        self.avgpool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        feature = self.conv1(x)
        feature = self.bn1(feature)
        feature = self.relu(feature)
        feature = self.maxpool(feature)
        feature = self.layer1(feature)
        feature = self.layer2(feature)
        feature = self.layer3(feature)
        feature = self.layer4(feature)
        out = self.avgpool(feature) #[,512,1,1]
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1) #[,512]
        return out
```

But I have `Using a target size (torch.Size([64, 1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([64, 512])) is deprecated. Please ensure they have the same size.`

I understand what it means. But I don't understand how to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Because the `x = x.view(-1, 49, 512)` reshape your tensor into a batch of tensors with shape (49x512). But your label is only a batch 1 dimension.

The GAT reduces the dimension for you and you remove it and only applying an activation is not enough. Activation does not change the size of the Tensor (aka 49x512 => 1).

One simple way is using pooling to reduce the 512 spaces into 1 and get the mean of a tensor (49x1) and reshape them into 1. The other way is flattening the 49x512 and applying an FC layer with single output.

But please provide more information why you dont want to use the GAT?

Comment: Thanks! I want to campare results for Resnet with GAT and for Resnet Without GAT

Comment: I don't understand at all how to use ```pooling``` in Pytorch. Now I try ```MaxPool1D``` but I have mistake ```module 'torch.nn' has no attribute 'MaxPooling1D'```

Comment: you have to use the pool from the graph lib. Maxpool1D is for CNN... https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/nn.html#pooling-layers